# How to send FCM web data messages to a specific open tab of that website using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a CURL of data message to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send using my endpoint.
The issue I am facing is I have multiple open tabs of my website. I want to receive data only on specific tab. But currently I am getting data message on another tab where that message is of no use. Can we send that data message to a specific page or to all open tabs. I am new on FCM and have a little knowledge regarding this. Below I am pasting my onMessage() event code.

```
messaging.onMessage ( function ( payload )
{
    if ( typeof payload.notification !== "undefined" )
    {
        var notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
        var notificationURL = payload.notification.click_action;
        var notificationOptions = 
        {
            body: payload.notification.body,
            icon: payload.notification.icon,
            badge: payload.notification.badge,
            subtitle: payload.notification.subtitle
        };

        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then ( function ( )
        {
             var notification = new Notification ( notificationTitle, notificationOptions );
             notification.onclick = function ( event )
             {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  window.open ( notificationURL, '_blank' );
             }
        });
     }
     else
     {
          init_todo_room
          (
               payload.data.todo_room,
               payload.data.title,
               payload.data.icon,
               payload.data.remove_header,
               payload.data.remove_tools,
               "",
               payload.data.remove_user,
               payload.data.data,
           );
      }
  }
```

I don't know how to achieve that. My basic goal is that I want to reduce AJAX calls using FCM and load data on page as fast as I can. Therefore I am using data messages to initiate the modules of my webpage. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "I am getting data message on another tab": what makes this tab so special?

Comment: I have to initiate a todo room that is present on that specific page. Not on page where I am receiving data message.